# "Go for a ride" vs. "take rides"

Tags: meaning

I guess this might be intuitive for natives but I am rather confused with dictionary definitions. 
In one text about questioning subjects in a survey, there are two distinct sentences the respondent is expected to complete. As in the following, "go for a ride" and "take rides" are mentioned in two different sentences, while I assume they mean the same. Isn't it?

> Sentence stem: When you first get a car...
>   Women's responses:
>   . . . you can’t wait till you drive.
>   . . . you would go for a ride.
>   . . . you would take rides in it, naturally.
>   . . . you would put gas in it and go places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same thing. The only difference I can see is that "go for a ride" is talking about one trip, while "take rides" is talking about multiple.

Comment: Take rides is just a variant of "take a ride", which is equivalent to "go for a ride"